# Как добавить сформированное предсказание модели к фрейму данных?

Tags: r

Я обучила модель классификатор RF. Как я могу добавитьпредикт, полученный на тесте, к фрейму данных (в маем случае к test)?

```
data <- read.csv("C:\\DS_ABAG.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
attach(data)#

data <- transform(#
  data,
  BOUGHT_FLG=as.factor(BOUGHT_FLG)
)

#Модель 1 , без удаления зависимых переменных
set.seed(101) 
sample = sample.split (data $ BOUGHT_FLG , SplitRatio = .75)

train1 = subset(data, sample == TRUE)
test1  = subset(data, sample == FALSE)
dim (train) 
dim (test)

rf <- randomForest ( 
  BOUGHT_FLG ~., 
  data = train,
  #ntree=409,
  importance = TRUE
) 
rf

pred <- predict(rf, newdata=test[-161], type = "prob")
```

Comment: Не понимаю, у Вас не получается создать новый столбец в датафрейме?

Comment: Да. Я была убеждена, что добиться желаемого результата можно лишь путем джойна тестовой выборки с полученным предсказанием на ней (по индексу). Однако, все оказалось куда проще test$Pred <- predict(rf, newdata = test, type = 'response'). Спасибо за беспокойство

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test$Pred <- predict(rf, newdata = test, type = 'response')#Создание новой колонки
```